# How to keep ASP.NET Core app avoid periodic shutting down in IIS?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core 3 application. I hosted it in IIS (10.0.17763.1) with Windows 2019.

The app is designed to call itself every 30 minutes, and it works well.
Days later, I found it says "Application is shutting down..." in the log, which happens periodically.

I searched and found the below article, and did what it says (print screen).

[How to auto start and keep an ASP.NET Core web application running on IIS](https://taithienbo.medium.com/how-to-auto-start-and-keep-an-asp-net-core-web-application-running-on-iis-9acc0fb6784b)

[image]

However, shutting down still keeps happening.

How to resolve it?

Comment: Does your application handles root path "/"? I think "Health Check" checks for a 200 OK on root path if it doesn't respond with 200 OK it will shutdown.

Comment: could be app pool recycle?

Comment: Applications would normally shutdown on error.  Check Eventlog and see if you can find crashes/Exceptions.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to get an easy answer as there isn't documentation around that. All you might do is to dig into the source code of ASP.NET Core module and hope it provides enough insights, https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Servers/IIS/AspNetCoreModuleV2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last Friday, I installed the "application initialization", so far the application is running well without shutting down.
[image]